# Quantum confined stark effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

As far as the stark effect is concerned, I imagine that the quenching of the emission spectra occurs because of the increase in the distance between the expected values of the electron and hole cloud, but suppose, I have quantum dots in the strong confinement regime, wouldn't that mean I do not see quenching of my spectrum, since my excitons are already squeezed?

Answer (score 1):

The quantum confined Stark effect is about red shift of optical spectra. Yes, we observe less quenching in 3D quantum confinement, because applied electric field reduces overlapping between electron end holes wave functions less. Additionally, applied electrostatic field decrease the energy gap between electron and hole states, that results in the quantum confined Stark effect. Take a look on [this reference](http://pweb.cc.sophia.ac.jp/shimolab/html-e/qcse-e.html) and wikipedia page on the quantum confined Stark effect

Comment: so my question is that, the reduced overlap is not a must, because in the strong confinement region the excitons are already packed into spaces smaller than their confined radius, so an electric field might not be able to spatially remove them further....right?

Comment: yes, i think you are right